# Angularjs not saving data in particular field

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I am trying to save data in **name** field, but despite the POST request running without any error, mongodb collections shows only **_id** and **_v** updated.

In short, I am unable to save data in a particular field.

VIEW:

```
<div id="bookslist" class="row" ng-controller="poster as po">
<form ng-submit="po.createTodo()">
  <div class="col-sm-7 form-group">
    <label for="" class="col-sm-2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="" ng-model="po.book.name" class="col-sm-6">
   </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7 text-right">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('poster', ['$http', function($http) {
    var self = this;

     var config = {
                headers : {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8;'
                }
            };

    self.createTodo = function() {
      console.log('Ouch baby!!');
      $http.post('http://localhost:3000/test',{'name': self.book }, config)
        .then(function(response) {
          console.log(self.book);
          console.log('data is  '+response); // data is  [object Object]
          console.log(response + " added"); //[object Object] added

        }, function(errResponse) {
          console.log('Error: ' + errResponse.statusText);
          console.log(errResponse.status);
        });
    };
  }]);
```

Routes:

```
'use strict';
module.exports = function(app) {
  var bookList = require('../controllers/testController');


app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  res.header("Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8");
  next();
});

  app.route('/test')
    .get(bookList.list_all_books)
    .post(bookList.create_a_books);
};
```

testController.js (which I created when setting up API):

```
'use strict';

var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  menu = mongoose.model('test');

exports.list_all_menus = function(req, res) {
  menu.find({}, function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(menu);
    console.log(res);
  });
};

exports.create_a_menu = function(req, res) {
  var new_menu = new menu(req.body);
  new_menu.save(function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(menu);
  });
};



exports.read_a_menu = function(req, res) {
  menu.findById(req.params.menuId, function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(menu);
  });
};


exports.update_a_menu = function(req, res) {
  menu.findOneAndUpdate({_id: req.params.menuId}, req.body, {new: true}, function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json(menu);
  });
};


exports.delete_a_menu = function(req, res) {
  menu.remove({
    _id: req.params.menuId
  }, function(err, menu) {
    if (err)
      res.send(err);
    res.json({ message: 'bestseller_books successfully deleted' });
  });
};
```

Note:

1. POST and GET requests are working just fine using postman
2. Everytime I hit submit button, I see this long array in mongodb collection:
   {"_id":"5a3f7a406e4b781598c05e92","__v":0},{"_id":"5a3f7a53487cb51b347e2f5e","__v":0},{"_id":"5a3f7a5fd6a48b1ac0357054","__v":0}

with no names being saved, while **name** being the second field in collection.

3. I am not able to understand the usage of methods *create_a_menu, list_all_menus, read_a_menu* defined in testController.js. What is the use of these?

Comment: where are you saving data using node?

Comment: In my mongodb collection. DB server running on localhost. APIs are just fine.

Comment: I need to look at that code which gets the data from angular and saves it in the monodb, can you edit your question?

Comment: ummmm, I don't have it. So, do i need to create a nodejs file for saving data?

Comment: your Controller test_controller will have a method create_a_books, that is responsible for saving data in mongodb according to your nodejs code. Show its code.

Comment: Edited the question. Added new code snippet from testController which i created during nodejs API setup. Didn't figured out use of these methods.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161889/discussion-between-sudhir-kaushik-and-asim-raja).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried `$http.post('http://localhost:3000/test',{'name': self.book.name }, config)`  ?

as you are using `ng-model="po.book.name"` in the html template

or

just rename it to `book_name`

`$http.post('http://localhost:3000/test',{'name': self.book_name }, config)`

`ng-model="po.book_name"`

Comment: Yes. But no luck.

Comment: HTTP were the answers, but I was noob at that time. Thanks for the help though